# An unexpected error occurred at kong manager login

Tags: lua, api-gateway, kong

Summary:

I'm using version 2.3.2.0-alpine on Openshift. After all services start up, I try to login to the manager with user 'kong_admin' and I am getting the following error:

Additional Details & Logs:

AJAX:

```
Request URL: https://admin-kong-kong.apps-crc.testing/userinfo
Request Method: GET
Código de Status: 500
{"message":"An unexpected error occurred"}
```

> 10.217.0.1 - kong_admin [12/May/2021:00:14:29 +0000] "GET /auth HTTP/2.0" 200 0 "https://manager-kong-kong.apps-crc.testing/"
> "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML,
> like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.93 Safari/537.36 Edg/90.0.818.56"
> 10.217.0.1 - - [12/May/2021:00:14:29 +0000] "OPTIONS /userinfo HTTP/2.0" 200 0 "https://manager-kong-kong.apps-crc.testing/"
> "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML,
> like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.93 Safari/537.36 Edg/90.0.818.56"
> 2021/05/12 00:14:29 [error] 26#0: *8452 [lua] api_helpers.lua:444:
> handle_error(): /usr/local/share/lua/5.1/lapis/application.lua:401:
> /usr/local/share/lua/5.1/kong/api/routes/kong.lua:90: attempt to index
> field 'rbac' (a nil value) stack traceback:
> /usr/local/share/lua/5.1/kong/api/routes/kong.lua: in function
> 'ws_and_rbac_helper'
> /usr/local/share/lua/5.1/kong/api/routes/kong.lua:207: in function
> 'fn' /usr/local/share/lua/5.1/kong/api/api_helpers.lua:265: in
> function </usr/local/share/lua/5.1/kong/api/api_helpers.lua:248>
>
> stack traceback: [C]: in function 'error'
> /usr/local/share/lua/5.1/lapis/application.lua:401: in function
> 'handler' /usr/local/share/lua/5.1/lapis/application.lua:130: in
> function 'resolve' /usr/local/share/lua/5.1/lapis/application.lua:167:
> in function </usr/local/share/lua/5.1/lapis/application.lua:165> [C]:
> in function 'xpcall'
> /usr/local/share/lua/5.1/lapis/application.lua:173: in function
> 'dispatch' /usr/local/share/lua/5.1/lapis/nginx.lua:230: in function
> 'serve' /usr/local/share/lua/5.1/kong/init.lua:1452: in function
> 'admin_content' content_by_lua(nginx-kong.conf:536):2: in main chunk,
> client: 10.217.0.1, server: kong_admin, request: "GET /userinfo
> HTTP/2.0", host: "admin-kong-kong.apps-crc.testing", referrer:
> "https://manager-kong-kong.apps-crc.testing/"

Comment: Which DB are you using ? Can kong connect to it ?

Comment: yes! database is working with postgres